# Can any website use "add to home screen" features?

Tags: web-development, progressive-web-app

I'm trying to figure out a way to enable an add to home screen (A2HS) prompt from a normal website. Most of the tutorials and solutions I've found are meant for progressive web apps (PWAs).

Are there any ways A2HS can be enabled or emulated for a normal website?